# Laravel - One to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm having some problems with my relationship, being returned the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::ftpAccounts()
```

Here is my models:

Customer Model

```
class Customer extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'customers';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'status',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function ftpAccounts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FTPAccounts::class);
    }
}
```

FTP Accounts model

```
class FTPAccounts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ftp-accounts';

    protected $fillable = [
        'host',
        'user',
        'password',
        'status',
    ];

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
class AdminFTPAccountsController extends AdminBaseController
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(FTPAccountsRepository $repository)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.clientes.ftp.index', [
            'customers' => $this->repository->allFTPAccounts(),
            'title' => 'TESTE'
        ]);
    }

    public function getCreate()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.clientes.ftp.create', [
            'title' => 'Nova conta FTP'
        ]);
    }

    public function postCreate(CustomerFTPAccountCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $request->user()->customers()->ftpAccounts()->create([
            'host' => $request->host,
            'user' => $request->user,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]);

        return redirect('admin/clientes');
    }
}
```

What can it be? Did i do something wrong?

### ## Edit 01 ##

User model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'password', 'status'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

//    protected $casts = ['status' => 'boolean'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }

    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `User` model doesn't have any method called `ftpAccounts()`.

Comment: @JilsonThomas I want to relate the FTP accounts with the customer and not user, I do not know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you treating Request object like Model object here.

You need to create new object Customer object and use $request->get('user') just as variable in it.

I can't test your code, but you can try something like this:

```
$customer = Customer::where('user', $request->get('user');

$ftpAccount = new FTPAccount;
$ftpAccount->host = $request->get('host');
$ftpAccount->user = $request->get('user');
$ftpAccount->password = $request->get('password');

$customer->ftpAccounts()->save();
```

Comment: How to proceed? I have no idea how to do this, I'm new with Laravel =/

Comment: Look at updated code. I can't test it, but I think you got the idea.

Comment: Yes, but I said I can't test your code. Look at the code, try to understand how it works and play with it. For example, I don't know what you get in `$request->user` (id or name or whatever) and I don't know should it be a `user` or `user_id` or even `id`. So, just try to understand how it works and I'm sure you'll make my code work by doing some little fix.

Comment: `$request->user()`  always returns the Auth user instance.

Comment: If `$request` is an instance of `Request` class, then `$request->user()` will return the currently authenticated user instance. If you want to access a field with a name `user` from the form request, that will be `$request->input('user')`. I'm using `$request->user()` in my code and it works perfect. :)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin `$request->user()` always return the Auth user, it's a default from laravel I think

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I meant `$request->get('user')`, was confused by your original code, sorry. Still, I believe my approach will work for you.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::ftpAccounts()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$customers = $request->user()->customers;


foreach($customers as $customer)
{
    $customer->ftpAccounts()->create([
            'host' => $request->host,
            'user' => $request->user,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]);

}
```

This will give you a head start.

Comment: But, wait. Can you also post the `User` model in your question?

Comment: Okay, did you try the one I gave you?

Comment: Yeah, nothing happens

Comment: What happens when you do `dd($request->user()->customers);` ?

Comment: Return an empty array

Comment: So that means you don't have any customers for that specific user.

Comment: I just want to assign the `ftpAccount()` to the `customer()` as I assign the `customer()` to `user()`, do not want the `user()` has connection with `ftpAccount()`

Comment: When you get all the customers associated with a user, you are getting null. That means there is no customer for that user. So it's not possible to call a method on null.

Comment: Make sure that you are returning some customers for that user or add a check before calling the `ftpAccount()` method to see if there're any customers for that user.